# By means of local Cauchy theorem find: $(i)\int_{|z|=1}\sqrt{9-z^2}dz; (ii) \int_{|z|=1}(z^2+2z)^{-1}dz; (iii)\int_{|z+i|=3/2}(z^4+z^2)^{-1}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

By means of local Cauchy theorem find: $(i)\int_{|z|=1}\sqrt{9-z^2}dz; (ii) \int_{|z|=1}(z^2+2z)^{-1}dz; (iii)\int_{|z+i|=3/2}(z^4+z^2)^{-1}$

(i) Since $f$ is analytic for all $\mathbb{C}$ and $|z|=1$ is a closed path, one has to $\int_{|z|=1}\sqrt{9-z^2}dz=0$.

(ii) I know that P is analytic in all points except $z=0, z=-2$, so how can I use the theorem here? Also the path is not where $f$ is analytic, could you modify this?

(iii) I know that $f$ is analytic in all points except $z=0, z=\pm i$, and besides all these points are in $|z+i|=3/2$ minus $z=i$, how can I do in this case then? Thank you very much.

Comment: $(i)$ that $f$ is not analytic everywhere.

Comment: @zhw. Why?.....

Comment: Where do you think $\sqrt z$ is defined as an analytic function?

Comment: @zhw. In all points except $z=0$?

Comment: $\sqrt z$ cannot be extended analytically to any domain that completely encircles $0$. $0$ itself cannot be included, but you also cannot define it on, for example, an annulus about the origin, because when you circle the origin, the value of $\sqrt z$ is multiplied by $-1$. So at some point, you have to have a discontinuity. However, this a problem only with the introductory statement in your explanation of (i), not the conclusion. $f$ is not analytic on all of $\Bbb C$, but it can be defined analytically on a neighborhood of $\{z\mid |z| \le 1\}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair 
How can you define analytically in a neighborhood of zero? 
With this the problem is solved? The neighborhood in which it is defined to be analytic must contain the $0$? What about the other problems?

Comment: $\sqrt z$ has a singularity at $0$, but you have $\sqrt {9-z^2}$. It has singularities at $3$ and $-3$, both of which are outside the circle $|z| = 1$. You cannot go completely around either one of those singularities without having a discontinuity. But there is no need to run that discontinuity through the unit circle. You could choose to have the discontinuity along $(-\infty,-3]$ and $[3, \infty)$, for instance. Or along one side of the circle $|z|=3$. Either choice leaves you with $\sqrt {9-z^2}$ analytic around and inside the unit circle, so Cauchy's theorem applies.

Comment: As for the other two problems. I don't know how you are supposed to do this "by Cauchy's Theorem", which requires analycity on the interior. Now, if you were told to do it by *Cauchy's Integral formula*, that would be another matter, as they fall easily to it.